# JanusGraph vertex.edges() returns a RelationConstructor rather an Iterator<Edge>

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm trying basic JanusGraph operations on JVM.

When I attempt to simply create an edge between two vertices and calling `vertex1.edges()` I'm getting a result of `org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor` rather `Iterator<Edge>`, which is against [api](https://static.javadoc.io/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.1.1/org/janusgraph/graphdb/vertices/AbstractVertex.html#edges-org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Direction-java.lang.String...-).

I could regenerate the same result on Gremlin console once as shown below. But I'm getting proper `org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator` in my subsequent attempts.

```
gremlin> person = graph.addVertex(label, 'person')
==>v[163844144]
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> person2 = graph.addVertex(label, 'anotherperson')
==>v[245764240]
gremlin> person.addEdge("knows", person2);
==>e[2pjoxy-2pjqy8-29ed-42bkwg][163844144-knows->245764240]
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> person.class
==>class org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.StandardVertex
gremlin> mye = person.edges(Direction.BOTH, "knows")
==>e[2pjoxy-2pjqy8-29ed-42bkwg][163844144-knows->245764240]
gremlin> mye.class
==>class org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1$1
```

Could someone please explain why and/or suggest a workaround?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting back `class org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1$1`. Take notice of the `$1$1` which is indicating that you are dealing with an anonymous class within `RelationConstructor`. In particular, you are getting back this [`Iterator`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.2.0/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/transaction/RelationConstructor.java#L47) from the method `readRelation()`. To be sure, you could have called `mye instanceof Iterator` in your session to verify.

In this example below, I've added `null` to the end of the `mye` assignment to prevent the Gremlin Console [auto-iteration](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration) behavior.

```
gremlin> mye = person.edges(Direction.BOTH, "knows"); null
==>null
gremlin> mye instanceof Iterator
==>true
gremlin> myedge = (mye.hasNext()) ? mye.next() : null
==>e[2pjoxy-2pjqy8-29ed-42bkwg][163844144-knows->245764240]
gremlin> myedge.class
==>class org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.CacheEdge
```

Comment: This is certainly helpful. Your answer addresses few other doubts I had. Thanks Jason! Really appreciated!